# Grab 8 characters after a particular string

Tags: php, string

I have a long string that will have 8 characters that I need to get out of it.  The 8 characters always happen after a specific number.

example:

blahblah1234WMCRCA01therestofthisisntimportant

Out of that I need to set a variable to the 8 characters after 1234 which would be WMCRCA01

Comment: Investigate [`strpos()`](http://php.net/strpos) and [`substr()`](http://php.net/substr) or better yet a [regex](http://regexp.info).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help:

```
$string = "blahblah1234WMCRCA01therestofthisisntimportant";
$startingString = "1234";
$startingStringAt = strpos($string, $startingString);
if (false === $startingStringAt) {
    echo "Could not find the \"$startingString\"";
} else {
    $eightCharacters = substr($string, $startingStringAt + 4, 8);
    echo "Eight characters found: " . $eightCharacters;
}
```

It is a complex solution including the case where no preceding "1234" string occurs in the base string.

Comment: This worked for me.  I was actually trying to figure out if I could somehow use substr and strpos to do it but couldnt get it right.